# How do I create a string array type that doesn't allow names of keys of another type?

Tags: typescript

To illustrate what I'm looking for:

```
interface Thing {
  id: string
  name: string
  amount: number
}

type OtherProps = string[] // What goes in here instead of `string[]`?

function processOtherProps(props: OtherProps) {
  throw new Error("unimplemented")
}

processOtherProps(["someOtherProp"]) // Ok
processOtherProps(["name"]) // Compiler error because "name" is a key of Thing
processOtherProps(["someOtherProp", "amount"]) // Compiler error because "amount" is a key of Thing
```

How do I declare `OtherProps` in a way that produces the expected outputs in the last three lines?

Comment: There is no specific type that works how you want; negated types do not exist in TypeScript. You’ll need to make `processOtherProps` generic. On mobile now so if I don’t get to it I’m sure someone else will explain. Good luck!

Comment: Is it no possible through a combination of the conditional operator ` ? : ` and the type `never`? I tried this for a while but couldn't figure out myself

Comment: No, there is no specific type in TypeScript like "all `string` except `keyof Thing`".  Conditional types do not give you this.  Had *negated types* as in [ms/TS#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) been implemented, you could have written `string & not keyof Thing`.  You can use generic types, but it would require something like `type OtherProps<K extends string> = Exclude<K, keyof Thing>[]` and then you carry `K` around everywhere, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG5v0N). If you want me to write that up as an answer, let me know (although the existing answer is similar)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a generic function as @jcalz stated.  Basically, you can take in a generic array that must be readonly (via `as const`) then make sure none of the values in the array are keys in `Thing`.

```
interface Thing {
  id: string
  name: string
  amount: number
}

function processOtherProps<T extends readonly string[]>(props: T[number] extends Exclude<T[number], keyof Thing> ? T : never) {
  throw new Error("unimplemented")
}

processOtherProps(["someOtherProp"] as const) // Ok
processOtherProps(["name"] as const) // Compiler error because "name" is a key of Thing
processOtherProps(["someOtherProp", "amount"] as const) // Compiler error because "amount" is a key of Thing
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8CwAUMssACYBcyAzmFNkSSHALYRW30haPKsD2AV3BUQglgCNoRAL5EiMYQjDB+IZAAco-JNWoB5MOmgAFbRuoAeVMggAPSCDLVkUCHDJqANgE8adbABtAF0APgAKLX4LKlRAsUloYNsHCCcXAFE7BC9BMghrePEpKGCAGmQAawgffhg0TG5Q5AB+NGRRCAA3aABKPF4jbQB3ZBAIUYyobShwgCJhYBYNLwg2cAgyOd7ZeUIo3QMjU3NqcMC56n42Q2MoM2i55LgXBDVafoB6T+R9SqIDhA9LcTtEzhdmGwnnxXu8wF8fgBha4aYCrKC2ab8DFSBBwQTUFBzSEQOakFxwKo1ZB1BoMfbaQ4g+6nc6Xa4QZkPDRzCpzATCMDQl7IN4gD7Ib7IZHLNHQTEzZC4-GE5D8lhCcBk4AUql+WkYelAA)